# WebGL 3d Cylinder and 3d Cone ontop of each other

Tags: opengl, webgl

I am in the middle of making a Webgl program and need to create a Cylinder using triangle strips and a Cone ontop of it using triangle fans to create a tree for a simple game type program.

Any tips or methods I could use to do this, as I only understand how to make rectangular prisms at the moment. Im a beginner in WebGL all help is appreciated :)

```
// The Block class that creates a rectangular prism............used as steps/obstacles for player to avoid
// The constructor function for a block when its created
// Arguments: a vec3 location, a floating-point angle (degrees) and a vec3 scales
function Block(location, angle, scales) {
    var rs = mult(rotate(angle, [0,0,1]), scalem(scales));
    this.trs = mult(translate(location), rs);
}

// A block's render function
// Arguments:
//   offset - offset of vertices into current vertex attribute array
//   worldview - current worldview transformation
Block.prototype.render = function(offset, worldview) {
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(mvLoc, false, flatten(mult(worldview, this.trs)));
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, offset, Block.NV);
};

// The number of vertices to represent a cube (NV)
Block.NV = 36;

//Makes the vertices for the block/rectangle
Block.initModel = function() {

    // The 8 raw vertices of a cube
    var rawverts = [
        vec3(-0.5, -0.5,  0.5),
        vec3(-0.5,  0.5,  0.5),
        vec3( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5),
        vec3( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5),
        vec3(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5),
        vec3(-0.5,  0.5, -0.5),
        vec3( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5),
        vec3( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5)
    ];

    // A local array in which to develop the 36 vertices
    var vertices = [];

    // A nested function generating the vertices for each face
    function quad(a, b, c, d) {
        // if abcd is an anticlockwise winding on a face
        // then abc and acd are anticlockwise windings on its triangles
        var indices = [a, b, c, a, c, d];

        for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i) {
            vertices.push(rawverts[indices[i]]);
        }
    }

    //Generates the cube's faces
    function doCube() {
        // Use anticlockwise windings
        quad(1, 0, 3, 2);
        quad(2, 3, 7, 6);
        quad(3, 0, 4, 7);
        quad(6, 5, 1, 2);
        quad(4, 5, 6, 7);
        quad(5, 4, 0, 1);
    }

    doCube();
    return vertices;
}//end of block.initial model function

//Vertices to be intialised
Block.vertices = Block.initModel();
//end of block/rectangle class-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please show some effort and provide us with what you already have in the form of a code snippet, or how you draw other shapes in webGL.

Comment: I believe you should see the block class ive made with a friends help, i like the style of this type of rendering aswell.

Comment: Why do you need to use triangle strips and fans instead of just plain triangles? Almost no one use strips and fans. Certainly no AAA game engines. If they don't need them why do you? As for how to create them have to considering looking at [the source to three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/src/extras/geometries) or to [some other libraries](https://github.com/greggman/twgl.js/blob/master/src/primitives.js)?

Comment: As thats what ive been using before and would like to keep it that way for now to understand basics. Also I kind of understand that CylinderGeometry.js though where is the render part for it? How would they render that to the screen?

Comment: If you don't know WebGL at all then you should probably read something like http://webglfundamentals.org  If you just want to make cool stuff then you should probably use [three.js](http://threejs.org) instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the link, ill check it out and do some reading from the start, as i have a very limited basic knowledge of WebGL. Though could you explain how to render that cylinder, and cone? or would it be best to just finishing reading the material.